# ROS Answers SE migration: uninstall ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know how to uninstall ROS on ubuntu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28589/uninstall-ros/) by [monsterkappa](https://answers.ros.org/users/1863/monsterkappa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-02-26**:
If you install ROS by Synaptic, then you can uninstall ROS with Synaptic.
If you install ROS by terminal, then you execute this instrucction: "sudo apt-get remove ros"

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-27**:
This is a duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/28587/uninstall-ros, please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed with apt:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros
```

If you installed with svn:

```
rm -rf /path/to/your/ros/directory
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"uninstall ros" didn't work for me; I needed to say "uninstall ros-groovy"

---

Originally posted by [Joseph Landau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5098/joseph-landau/) with karma: 51 on 2013-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on 2013-07-01**:
sudo apt-get remove ros-* would be more extensive!